# Ng-src not calling function from scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an ngRepeat that iterates through a list of objects and displays them. These objects do not contain any images, but the ID can be used to fetch the image. In the contents of the ngRepeat, I want to show the image that corresponds to the object, and so I call a function within an ngSource to grab the image corresponding with the current object. However, the ngSource fails to load on the actual page.

HTML:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a ng-click="courseSelected(course.course_id)" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="course in searchResultData.courseList" id="searchResults">
    <div>
        <img ng-src="{{getLogoByCourse(course)}}"/>
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{course.name}}, {{course.city}}, {{course.state}}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text miscData" ng-show="course.price"><span>Price: {{course.price}}</span></p>
        <p class="list-group-item-text miscData">
            <span>Phone number: {{course.phone}}</span><br/>
            <span>Address: {{course.address}}</span><br/>
            <span>Website: {{course.website}}</span>
        </p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Directive Snippet:

```
$scope.getLogoByCourse = function(course) {
    console.log("Getting logo");
    courseFactory.getLogoByID(course.course_id)
        .then(function(result){
            console.log("logo: ", result);
            result = "app/images/directory/" + result.data[0];
            return result;
        }
    );
}

$scope.getImageByCourse = function(course) {
    courseFactory.getImagesByID(course.course_id)
        .then(function(result){
            console.log("Image: ", result);
            result = "app/images/directory/" + result.data[0];
            return result;
        }
    );
}
```

Contents of image tag on loaded page:

```
<img class="logo-img">
```

Comment: Are those functions declared in the controller scope? If they're declared in the directive scope, I don't see any custom directive in the HTML.

Comment: Sorry, the HTML is in the view loaded by the directive, and the functions are declared in the link field of the directive. I'm fairly confident it is the correct place, as other functions in the same place are successfully called from the html.

Comment: It should work fine. I don't understand where it is breaking. Can you create a quick , small jsFiddle example of your format.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `$scope.getLogoByCourse` doesn't actually return anything. It looks like you're trying return a value from a promise, but since that returns  asynchronously, you'll always just get `undefined` as the return value from `$scope.getLogoByCourse`.

You may want to consider getting all of the URLs at once and loading them into an array. Then you can attach each URL in the `ng-repeat` using the `$index` variable.

```
$scope.logos = [];

for (var i = 0; i < searchResultData.courseList.length; i++) {
    (function (j) {
        var course = searchResultData.courseList[j];
        courseFactory.getImagesByID(course.course_id)
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log("Image: ", result);
                result = "app/images/directory/" + result.data[0];
                $scope.logos[j] = result;
                $scope.$apply();
            }, function (error) {
                $scope.logos[j] = null;
            });
    )(i);
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<img ng-src="{{ logos[$index] }}" />
```

Comment: If I use this, logos comes out to http://puu.sh/qRUqr/4394994153.png, but the console log that outputs image produces the correct results.

Comment: Nevermind, fixed that. The url still isn't appearing on the loaded html though.

Comment: Just a sec, I think I figured it out. I'll post back once I'm sure.

Comment: Okay, it worksish, I was just running into a caching issue. The indexes aren't matching up, so once I fix that I'll post my solution and mark this solved.

Comment: Yes you're right, you have to assign each URL to the corresponding index. I updaed my answer yesterday to take that into account.